# building a .cab file

Tags: visual-studio-2008, icons, windows-mobile

I developed a `Windows mobile application` and now I'm building a `.cab file`, 
it is created and works fine, but when i try to uninstall it (since "settings>system>Remove programs" And select it from the list and clic "uninstal"..) after the uninstall I can see the app icon on my device... I navigate to "file explorer>programs" and the app icon and the database icon are there and i have to delete them manually...

Am i building my .cab file wrong?
Which would the best way to do a .cab file?

[This is the way to did it (with Microsoft Visual Studio 2008):](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dCCBoLnXGPY)

Answer (score 0):

A CAB uninstall will only remove the files that it installed.  If your app creates a database file, settings file, or anything else that wasn't explicitly in the CAB, it won't get removed unless you write [a custom Setup DLL](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/wince-winmobile-setupdll.html) that takes care of those pieces.